# Converting all values in a list of dictionaries to lowercase in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know that this is simple, but I could not figure it out.
I want to convert all values on a list of dictionaries that look like the one bellow to lowercase:

```
{'John greased ': ['Axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'wheel', 'enGine', ''], 
 'Maria testa': ['teste', 'teste', '', '', '', ''], 
 'Paul alleged ': ['truth', 'crime', 'facts', 'infidelity', 'incident', ''], 
 'Tracy freed ': ['animals', 'fish', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'pizza'], 
 'Lisa plowed ': ['field', 'Field', 'FIELD', 'bola', '', '']}
```

I tried using:

```
low = {k.lower():v.lower() for k, v in result.items()}
print(low)
```

But it won't work. Any suggestions on how to fix that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Your values are lists, so add a list comprehension:

```
{k.lower(): [i.lower() for i in v] for k, v in result.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> result = {'John greased ': ['Axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'wheel', 'enGine', ''], 
...  'Maria testa': ['teste', 'teste', '', '', '', ''], 
...  'Paul alleged ': ['truth', 'crime', 'facts', 'infidelity', 'incident', ''], 
...  'Tracy freed ': ['animals', 'fish', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'pizza'], 
...  'Lisa plowed ': ['field', 'Field', 'FIELD', 'bola', '', '']}
>>> {k.lower(): [i.lower() for i in v] for k, v in result.items()}
{'lisa plowed ': ['field', 'field', 'field', 'bola', '', ''], 'tracy freed ': ['animals', 'fish', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'pizza'], 'paul alleged ': ['truth', 'crime', 'facts', 'infidelity', 'incident', ''], 'maria testa': ['teste', 'teste', '', '', '', ''], 'john greased ': ['axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'wheel', 'engine', '']}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint({k.lower(): [i.lower() for i in v] for k, v in result.items()})
{'john greased ': ['axle', 'wheel', 'wheels', 'wheel', 'engine', ''],
 'lisa plowed ': ['field', 'field', 'field', 'bola', '', ''],
 'maria testa': ['teste', 'teste', '', '', '', ''],
 'paul alleged ': ['truth', 'crime', 'facts', 'infidelity', 'incident', ''],
 'tracy freed ': ['animals', 'fish', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'slaves', 'pizza']}
```

Comment: Perfect. Now I understand!  Thank yo very much!